# JavaScript redirect users based on browser language (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to show different tab on chrome extension using JavaScript, but it's not working.

In this case, it redirects only to `it.example.com` and when I change my browser language to English or French, thats script redirects only to `it.example.com`.

Can someone show me how I can redirect based on the browser language?

**I want to do different redirections for `it` and `fr`. Other languages should be redirected to English.**

newtab.html

```
<head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newtab.js"></script>
</head>
```

newtab.js

```
if (window.navigator.language === 'it') { 
window.location.href = 'https://it.example.com/';
}

if (window.navigator.language === 'fr') { 
window.location.href = 'https://fr.example.com/';
} 

else window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
```

Comment: Um, shouldn't your conditionals be using `===`, not `!=`?  It looks like you have your logic backwards.  Take your second conditional that says "If the language is not 'it', send the user to `it.example.com`".  That seems backwards.

Comment: Thank you very moch i have chnage it != to === and i have test it, but now that show only example.com and if I chnage the browser language in Italian that still ridirect me to example.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function redirectToSpecificPage() {
  var base = 'https://$1example.com/',
    replaceLng = function(toReplace, replaceWith) {
      return base.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
    },
    lngPages = {
      en: replaceLng(''),
      it: replaceLng('it.'),
      fr: replaceLng('fr.'),
      es: replaceLng('es.'),
    }
  window.location.href = lngPages[window.navigator.language.toLowerCase().slice(0,2)] || lngPages.base;
})();
```

Comment: thanks for yur help but this code do not work, so with this do not do any redirection

Comment: What does window.navigator.language show, if you enter it in your browser console?

Comment: that code show the newpage.html do not ridirect it on website

Comment: maybe somthing elese missing on my extension, but thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you changed all your `!=` for `===` like suggested in comments...

> I changed the browser language in Italian that still redirect me to example.com

It looks like none of your condition evaluated to `true`.

Be aware that the *language identification codes* often include a country "variant"... Like, for example, my browser language actually is `en-US` instead of just `en`. Here a [list](https://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes) that looks complete, which you should have a look.

Additionnally, I suggest you to use the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement, instead of if/else for this particular case.

```
var language = window.navigator.language;

var languageFistTwo = language.substr(0,1); // To only keep the first 2 characters.

switch (languageFistTwo) { 
  case "en":
    window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
    break;

  case "it":
    window.location.href = 'https://it.example.com/';
    break;

  case "fr":
    window.location.href = 'https://fr.example.com/';
    break;

  case "es":
    window.location.href = 'https://es.example.com/';
    break;

  default:
    window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mouch for your help, i have test this code, but that ridirect only in `example.com` and if browser language is example in Italian, really I don't know whats the problem, maybe I need to add some code and in my background.js on my extension, or somthing else, I really don't understand why is not working!

Comment: Check what the language is by console logging it: `console.log(window.navigator.language);`.

Comment: strangely it is en and if i change the browser language! Thanks again for you help

Comment: Same for me here... The language change in Chome setting does not reflect in that `console.log(navigator.language);`. I just found this: if you `console.log(navigator.languages)`, notice the ending "s", you get the *prefered language* array... in importance order. [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages#Browser_compatibility). -- That does not solve your problem... But may help. ;)

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I solved it in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. but this works only on chrome extension do not work on firefox :/

_locales/en/messages.json

```
   "example_default_search": {
    "message": "example.com",
    "description": ""
   }
```

_locales/it/messages.json

```
   "example_default_search": {
    "message": "it.example.com",
    "description": ""
   }
```

newtab.js

```
function localizeHtmlPage()
{
    //Localize by replacing __MSG_***__ meta tags
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
    for (var j = 0; j < objects.length; j++)
    {
        var obj = objects[j];

        var valStrH = obj.innerHTML.toString();
        var valNewH = valStrH.replace(/__MSG_(\w+)__/g, function(match, v1)
        {
            return v1 ? chrome.i18n.getMessage(v1) : "";
        });

        if(valNewH != valStrH)
        {
            obj.innerHTML = valNewH;
        }
    }
}

localizeHtmlPage();
```

newtab.html

```
<head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://__MSG_example_default_search__/'" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newtab.js"></script>
</head>
```